# Using math.random in button to set a select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, button, random

I'm trying to make a button that randomly sets a select option when clicked. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong though...

http://jsfiddle.net/GamerGorman20/nw8Ln6ha/25/

```
$('#rand').click(

        function() {
            randNum();
            var num = "";
            document.getElementById("mySelect").value.innerHTML = favWebComics[num];
    });

    var randNum = function() {
        num = Math.round(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        return num;
    };
```

The shown code is only a small part of the larger script housed in the linked jsfiddle.

I plan to add more selections later, but I want to get the code figured out before I spend time on those.

Worth mentioning, my understanding of this is very limited, so keeping the advice simple is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You cannot set innerHTML of a select like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant part of your code that you will need to change will look like this when complete (see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw8Ln6ha/28/)):

```
$('#rand').click(function() {
    var $select = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
        max = $select.getElementsByTagName('option').length - 1;

    $select.selectedIndex = randNum(1, max);
    myFunction();
});

var randNum = function(min, max) {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return num;
};

var myFunction = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = favWebComics[x][1];
    document.getElementById("web").innerHTML = favWebComics[x][0];
    document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML = "Tags: " + favWebComics[x][2];
};
```

I haven't changed the style or structure of your code, but just some of the basic properties.

The problem you have is with `innerHTML`. You cannot set `innerHTML` on an element's `value`.

Instead, what you can do is generate a random number and set the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element to that random number.

Then, you'll call the function that displays the images and whatnot that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `select` with `innerHTML` like this:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").value.innerHTML = favWebComics[num];
```

You have to instead change the value, and apply the change like so

```
$("#mySelect").val("New text").change();
```

or

```
$("#mySelect").prop('selectedIndex', index).change();
```